# SQL Count returns too many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, left-join

I have the following SQL statement:

```
    SELECT 
    O.id,
    O.name,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(U.id)
        FROM
            User U
        WHERE
            U.organization_id = O.id) AS num_users
FROM
    Organization O
```

The User table and the Organization table is bound by something called `organization_id`

When i execute this statement i get the follwoing (bad) result:

```
id |  name   | num_users
------------------------
 1 |  MyOrg  |     2
 2 |  MyOrg  |     0
 3 | testOrg |     0
```

Can anyone tell me how i can get a result that will only produce 1 line pr. Organization?

Note that i have tried with `DISTINCT` But without getting a better result

Comment: `DISTINCT` will not work because of the unique `id` numbers.

Comment: SELECT 
    DISTINCT O.name,
    (SELECT 
            COUNT(U.id)
        FROM
            User U
        WHERE
            U.organization_id = O.id) AS num_users
FROM
    Organization O Does not work either

Comment: @Marc Rasmussen: So your table is called Organization and it has an ID per organization, but two organizations happen to be just one organization actually in case their name matches? Is this what you are saying???

Comment: It seems like you have more than one organization named 'MyOrg'. The result seems fine to me, but how do you want to handle that case? Please show your desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/73ec8/15/1) demonstrating the below queries:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.id SEPARATOR ', '), O.name, 
       COUNT(U.organization_id) AS MyCount
FROM Organization O
LEFT JOIN User U ON U.organization_id = O.id
GROUP BY O.name;
```

Or, if you don't need the `id` field then:

```
SELECT O.name, COUNT(U.organization_id) AS MyCount
FROM Organization O
LEFT JOIN User U ON U.organization_id = O.id
GROUP BY O.name;
```

Comment: With `INNER JOIN`, you won't get any `0` counts.

Comment: With `LEFT JOIN` and `COUNT(*)`, organizations with 0 users will artificially add 1 to the count. E.g. 'MyOrg' will show 3 users, when it should be 2.

Comment: **@Marcus Adams**, I updated my answer using a `UNION` to get all `o.id` that are not in the first query.

Comment: I liked your first answer better. Hint: just change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(U.organization_id)`.

Comment: **Marcus Adams**, wow thanks, I don't know what I was thinking.  I updated my answer.  It may be a Tuesday but my brain seems to be working like a Monday.  Should have noticed that myself.